# Using iPhone Configuration Utility for custom app

Tags: iphone, configuration, enterprise, utility

Can Apple's iPhone Configuration Utility be used to configure my own application? I have created an app with a number of different settings, and I would like the option of having someone in a corporate setting having the option of configuring the settings via a configuration profile like what Apple provides for their own apps using iPhone Configuration Utility.   What are my options here?   Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you can't use the current version of the iPhone Configuration Utility (3.2) to configure anything but the predefined configuration settings built into the OS (things like VPN, WiFi, ActiveSync ect...)

You could have your application call into a central server (when it is run) and punch its own settings. However this won't include things like enabling GPS location tracking or push notifications, since the user gets the final say on these settings (when they are prompted).

Comment: "Leverage" does not mean "use".

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the settings app on the home screen, it's easy. All you need is a plist:

Here's the documentation for implementing it. It looks like a lot of work, but it's really not. They just have a lot of that marketing style text that they love to put around the documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html

Comment: no, i think he means the apple enterprise iphone configuration utility, http://support.apple.com/kb/DL851

Comment: Ok, that makes a little bit more sense. I didn't know of that thing's existence until you put up that link. I only program for fun.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your settings on your own server and let your app interpret them. iPCU is only for configuring iPhone built-in apps.

If you do need configure them in an easy way, checkout the app, iPCU on AppStore. Pre-config settings such as email, vpn, calendars... and send them to your fellow co-workers via an Email. After installing the profile, their iOS devices are ready for the enterprises use right away.

iTunes:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ipcu/id513585146?mt=8